Choice of local holomorphic coordinates on Hermitian manifolds
I'm reading Fangyang Zheng's Complex Differential Geometry. I have a question about the details while reading a proof of a lemma. This question can be described as follows:

Let $(M, h)$ and $(N, g)$ be Hermitian manifolds and $f:M\rightarrow N$ be a holomorphic map. Fix a point $p\in M$, then we can choose local holomorphic coordinates $ \left(z_{1}, \ldots, z_{n}\right) $ of $M$ and $ \left(w_{1}, \ldots, w_{m}\right) $ of $N$, respectively, such that
$$h_{i\bar j}(p)=\delta_{ij},\quad g_{i\bar j}(f(p))=\delta_{ij},$$
and at $p$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n f_i^\alpha\overline{f_i^\beta}=0\text{ for any }\alpha\neq\beta,\text{ and }\sum_{\alpha=1}^m f_i^\alpha\overline{f_j^\alpha}=0\text{ for any }i\neq j,$$
where $f_i^\alpha$ is the partial derivative of the $\alpha$-th component function of $f$ with respect to $z_i$.

$h_{i\bar j}(p)=\delta_{ij}$ and $g_{i\bar j}(f(p))=\delta_{ij}$ is easy but I have no idea why the local holomorphic coordinates can be chosen such that at $p$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i^\alpha\overline{f_i^\beta}=0$ and $\sum_{\alpha=1}^m f_i^\alpha\overline{f_j^\alpha}=0$. The book says, by a constant unitary change of the coordinates $z$ and $w$, we may assume that at $p$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n f_i^\alpha\overline{f_i^\beta}=0\text{ for any }\alpha\neq\beta,\text{ and }\sum_{\alpha=1}^m f_i^\alpha\overline{f_j^\alpha}=0\text{ for any }i\neq j.$$
However, I did not understand his meaning. I once tried to write these two equations as
$$(f_1^\alpha,\cdots,f_n^\alpha)\cdot(\overline{f_1^\beta},\cdots,\overline{f_n^\beta})=0,\quad(f_i^1,\cdots,f_i^m)\cdot(\overline{f_j^1},\cdots,\overline{f_j^m})=0$$
but I didn't know what else to do. Can someone tell me how this is derived scrupulously? Any help would be appreciated!
EDITED:
If the coordinates change formulas are
$$\left(\frac\partial{\partial z_1},\cdots,\frac\partial{\partial z_n}\right)=\left(\frac\partial{\partial\tilde z_1},\cdots,\frac\partial{\partial\tilde z_n}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
  \dfrac{\partial\tilde z_1}{\partial z_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial\tilde z_1}{\partial z_n} \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  \dfrac{\partial\tilde z_n}{\partial z_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial\tilde z_n}{\partial z_n}
\end{matrix}\right)$$
and
$$\left(\frac\partial{\partial w_1},\cdots,\frac\partial{\partial w_m}\right)=\left(\frac\partial{\partial\tilde w_1},\cdots,\frac\partial{\partial\tilde w_m}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
  \dfrac{\partial\tilde w_1}{\partial w_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial\tilde w_1}{\partial w_m} \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  \dfrac{\partial\tilde w_m}{\partial w_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial\tilde w_m}{\partial w_m}
\end{matrix}\right),$$
then since $f$ is holomorphic,
$$df\left(\frac\partial{\partial z_1},\cdots,\frac\partial{\partial z_n}\right)=\left(\frac\partial{\partial w_1},\cdots,\frac\partial{\partial w_m}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f^\alpha}{\partial z_i}\right),$$
$$df\left(\frac\partial{\partial\tilde z_1},\cdots,\frac\partial{\partial\tilde z_n}\right)=\left(\frac\partial{\partial\tilde w_1},\cdots,\frac\partial{\partial\tilde w_m}\right)\left(\frac{\partial\tilde f^\alpha}{\partial\tilde z_i}\right).$$
Then we have
$$\left(\frac{\partial\tilde f^\alpha}{\partial\tilde z_i}\right)=\left(\frac{\partial\tilde w_\alpha}{\partial w_\beta}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f^\beta}{\partial z_j}\right)\left(\frac{\partial\tilde z_j}{\partial z_i}\right)^{-1}.$$
Since the change matrices are unitary,
\begin{align*}
0=\sum_{i=1}^n \tilde f_i^\alpha\overline{\tilde f_i^\beta}&=\sum_i\frac{\partial\tilde w_\alpha}{\partial w_\gamma}f_j^\gamma\frac{\partial z_j}{\partial\tilde z_i}\overline{\frac{\partial\tilde w_\beta}{\partial w_\delta}f_k^\delta\frac{\partial z_k}{\partial\tilde z_i}}\\
&=\sum_j\frac{\partial\tilde w_\alpha}{\partial w_\gamma}f_j^\gamma\overline{f_j^\delta}\overline{\frac{\partial\tilde w_\beta}{\partial w_\delta}}.
\end{align*}

The vanishing of the sums says that the columns (resp. rows) of the differential matrix $Df = (f^\alpha_i)_{i\alpha}$ are pairwise orthogonal wrt. $g$ (resp. $h$). Not sure if this helps?

This is essentially linear algebra. How does the Jacobian at $p$ change if you change the coordinates on both $M$ and $N$?

@Deane I have edited my post and added my process. So do we just need to choose a unitary matrix $\left(\dfrac{\partial\tilde w_\alpha}{\partial w_\beta}\right)$ so that the vector $(\tilde f_1^\alpha,\cdots,\tilde f_n^\alpha)$ is orthogonal to vector $(\tilde f_1^\beta,\cdots,\tilde f_n^\beta)$? And another vanishing sum determines the choice of unitary matrix $\left(\dfrac{\partial\tilde z_j}{\partial z_i}\right)$

In the last equation, why does it start with $0=$?

The second to last equation, written using matrices, is of the form $$\tilde{M} = UMV^*, $$ where $U, V$ are unitary matrices. Now use the singular value decomposition.

@Deane So not only can we make the two sums vanish, but we can even make the matrix $(f^\alpha_i)_{i\alpha}$ be diagonal.

Yes. This is an example of the following principle: 99% of basic questions in differential geometry can be answered using only linear or multilinear algebra on the tangent or cotangent space at a point.
